# How to get the OAuth2 access token using Post method

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, spring-security, oauth-2.0, cxf

Im trying to configure oauth2 with spring security, i took an example from

```
https://github.com/neel4software/SpringSecurityOAuth2
```

now my problem is i need to get an oauth2 access token using a post method instead of get, below is how the token end point is configured in spring security xml

this is the GET method URL end point that is working

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringRestSecurityOauth/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=restapp&client_secret=restapp&username=beingjavaguys&password=spring@java
```

and this is how the end point configuration done in spring security xml

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
            parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

in order to access it using a POST method i have tried to access below end point using

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringRestSecurityOauth/oauth/token
```

with the given parameters as a payload in rest client(i have also tried to give these parameters as header parameters)

```
grant_type: password
client_id: restapp
client_secret: restapp
username: beingjavaguys
password: spring@java
```

but each time i tried to access it using rest client it allways prompt me for a username and password which i don't know. i gave username as "beingjavaguys" and password as "spring@java" which didn't work. im using Oauth2 in first time

Answer (score 6):

To generate a oauth 2.0 token with password grant_type, below is the process

```
credential = base64Encode(clientId:secret)
```

value of credential is `cmVzdGFwcDpyZXN0YXBw`

now here is how your request should look like,

```
POST /SpringRestSecurityOauth/oauth/token

HOST: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic cmVzdGFwcDpyZXN0YXBw
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Payload:
grant_type=password&username=beingjavaguys&password=spring%40java
```

Comment: Thanks Abishka, You saved my day!. and can you explain why did you make this request as basic authorization also why did you make the client id and secret key encoded?

Comment: It is as OAuth 2.0 specification. Here is the link https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-39

If this was correct answer please accept the response as answer.

Comment: Could you provide more details to your answer? thanks